# Do Magrittr pipes actually "stream"? Or are they just syntactic sugar?

Tags: r, tidyr, magrittr

Are the pipes from tidyr / magrittr actually doing a streamed pipe operation?  Or are these "pipes" just syntactic sugar?

For example, when connecting to a database server to pull down records to apply some model, is the entire data set downloaded first before the next step in the pipe executed?  Or is it being streamed across all steps in an async lazy-load manner?

The background here relates to the need to avoid loading tons of records in memory *prior* to applying a model to the data set.

If piping operations are streaming, then in theory we could avoid running into memory limitations.  But, it's not clear if we are using the term "pipe" here in a non-traditional manner.

Comment: AFAIK, the way a pipeline works is: it first captures your call environment, converts all functions in a pipeline into a sequence of function calls, and then executes them one by one if it receives any input from its leftmost position. That said, whether your pipeline is lazy or not almost entirely depends on the sequence of constituent functions. For example, if you use the `dbplyr` package, the pipeline would then be quite lazy. No actual query is performed unless you explicitly call a `collect()` function. If the functions used do not have build-in laziness, then the pipeline won't help.

Comment: the `dbplyr` package is lazy. Standard `dplyr` isn't (to the best of my knowledge).  (This is my vague way of saying what @ekoam said in more detail.)

Comment: Nothing in [the source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr) indicates streaming. I believe it's been suggested that the pipe symbol be pronounced "then", implying that statements are executed in full, one by one.